# Why are my textures not showing but just the texture color?

Tags: texturing

I have been trying to make a knife weapon of a game I'm making. However I have a problem where I import the images knife parts, and it does not show the real image, but just the color of the image.
Is there anyway to fix that? 
Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRuru.jpg)

Comment: Hello and welcome :). You need to UV unwrap your model if you want to use textures.

Comment: THANKS Jachym Michal, I fix it!